# .nunit file ignoring configfile paramater

Tags: c#, nunit

I have set up a .nunit file to specify a local and remote test suite App.config. Here is my code :

```
<NUnitProject>
  <Settings activeconfig="local"/>
  <Config name="local" configfile="App.config">
    <assembly path="bin\Debug\Proj.dll"/>
  </Config>
  <Config name="remote" configfile="App.Remote.config">
    <assembly path="bin\Debug\Proj.dll"/>
  </Config>
</NUnitProject>
```

Now, when I run the following command in my command line

```
"nunit3-console" "test_runner.nunit" /config:remote
```

It is still running off of the App.config and not the App.Remote.config file I specified in the Config block.. Am I missing something here? Do I need to have some sort of referance in my App.config?

Comment: Is the config file you want to use in the bin\Debug directory when you run?

Comment: @Charlie no, I placed both the .nunit file and the App.Remote.config file in the same directory. They are both located in project root

Answer (score 0):

I missed the reply to my comment! In case you haven't already done so, you should ensure that the config file is copied to the output directory.